# Windows 7 + Outlook 2007 connection drop following Sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have noticed a similar question to this having carried out a search but the answers given are unfortunately not helpful in my situation.

I am currently carrying out Windows 7 deployment and a handful of pilot users have mentioned that when taking their machine out of *sleep mode* they are asked for their Outlook credentials before being able to reconnect to the Exchange server. I believed that the issue was related to the option to allow the NIC power down when in *sleep mode* in order to conserve power - however having made the relevant changes within the build process I have noticed that the problem persists. Another reason why I am certain it does not relate to the NIC card powering down is that all other network connectivitiy functions correctly when removing the machine from *sleep mode*.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I envisage the service desk being inundated with end user queries as to whether the network is down due to Outlook requesting credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a problem with autodiscover on Exchange. And double check that your DNS server has an entry for your Exchange server.